# Get list of IPs of hosts in group with Jinja2 filter

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

I'm building a couple of roles where I need to give the config the IP addresses of all hosts in a specified group as a comma separated string.

Is there a jinja2 combination of filters (like map, match, select, join etc) that produce the same as this:

```
{% set comma = joiner(",") %}
{% for hostname in groups['mongodb'] %}
{{ comma() }}{{ hostvars[hostname].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{%- endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is almost exact answer in the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers)...

Slight modification, and here you go:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['mongodb'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}"
```

Comment: That's very cool. Hypothetically, how could we have a default value incase one of the host doesn't have the object ?